# Avoid storing image in temp folder iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am working on a project, in that I have implemented the file upload option using choose from library option. When the user clicks the gallery option, it photos/album folder will be opened and we can pick the image. The selected image will be received from the image picker.

```
func pickImage(_ sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .camera) {
     imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    cameraOverlay?.buttonTakePicture.isEnabled = true
    defaultSourceType = sourceType
    if defaultSourceType == .camera {           
         imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType
        imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = cameraOverlay
        imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false
    }
    else{
        imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType
    }
```

In this case, the selected image is stored in the tmp directory, I don’t want to store the image from the directory.

For UIDocumentPickerViewController, there is option like below. We have e tried and it’s not stored in the tmp directory. Is this any other way to avoid storing the image in tmp directory for UIImagePickerController as well.

```
let importMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF),String(kUTTypeImage)], in: .open)
```

We can use clean tmp directory option once the image picked, but I want to know is any other way to not store the image in tmp directory.

Comment: Try `PHPickerViewController` instead on iOS 14+. It will probably return the direct URLs into the asset library.

Comment: Thanks, @RobZombie. It means there is no way in UIImagePickerController right? Anyway I will try PHPickerViewController